# Connecting to web server running on Windows machine from Mac over Ethernet

Tags: windows, networking, mac, ethernet, webserver

I have a Windows laptop running a web server on some port - say `localhost:8000`. I can access the website from the Windows laptop fine. I have a MacBook which wants to access the website being hosted on the Windows laptop. I can connect them via an Ethernet cable.

Here's what I tried:

- Started running a dummy HTTP server on Windows laptop using `python -m http.server`
- Connected MacBook and Windows laptop with Ethernet cable
- Ran `ipconfig` on Windows and recovered the `IPv4` address under the heading `Ethernet adapter Ethernet:`
- Tried connecting to `<Windows IPv4>:8000` from my web browser on macOS, but failed to do so (it just never connects so I'm guessing it timed out).

Any help on on how to resolve this would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: From an admin elevated command prompt on the Windows machine run `netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off` and then test from the Mac if the `http://<IPAddress>:8000` is accessible. If it is accessible you will want to run from the same admin elevated command prompt: `netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state on` and then `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule localport=8000 dir=in name="Inbound TCP Port 8000" protocol=TCP enable=yes action=allow profile=private,domain,public` .... now try and confirm it you can connect. If so let me know and I'll explain in more detail with an answer.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I cannot connect after disabling the firewall

Comment: After pinging the Windows IPv4 address, I get several of the following `Request timeout for icmp_seq 0`

Comment: Just as a peanut gallery comment but is there a particular reason that you aren't using e.g. a router or similar? Obviously it's possible to do this (direct connection via Ethernet) but it feels like introducing an extra point of failure. Also, while I could definitely be mistaken, my understanding is that for many "direct" connections (no hub, etc.), you often need a cross-over Ethernet cable vs a standard patch cord.

Comment: How can I do this with a router?

Comment: Are you sure the web server is bound to `localhost:8000` vs `0.0.0.0:8000`?

Comment: @grawity yes, the python web server is hosted on local host

Comment: That's not quite what I was asking... What listen / bind address is specified? (Does it have a `--bind` option?)